# Compare two list - check if one list contains value of second

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to compare one list of string (list1) with next list (list2) values (next list of string). I found plenty of solution with sequence ordering but in my case it does not matter.

My list of string will be for example:

```
List<string> myList1 = new List() {'123', '234','345'}
```

Right now I need to create a method which will take list "1" as a parameter and then loops (?) through the list "2" to check if values from list 1 are in the list 2

```
public bool IsValueInsideTheList(string[] orderNumbersToFindInTheList)
{
 //Here I suppose I need to do the looping with foreach/ for to check if value of list1 are in the list2
}
```

Comment: Do duplicates matter? For example, should `IsValueInsideTheList` return true for `["1", "1", "2"]` and `["1", "2", "2"]`? What about lists of different sizes? Should `["1", "2"]` and `["1", "2", "3"]` return true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```cs
IEnumerable<string> list1;
IEnumerable<string> list2;

// ...
var containsMatches = list1.Any(item => list2.Contains(item));
```

I used `IEnumerable<string>` here because this will work for any lists of that type, not just a `List<string>` and a `string[]`.

Comment: This will be true even if the item from list 1 has an higher index than the match on list 2. I think OP wants to compare only values from the forward indexes of the value actually being compared.

Comment: @DavidRodrigues, I reread the question and I see no evidence of that. I think you may be inferring something that was not implied. I could be wrong, of course. Questions are not always worded clearly.

Comment: Correct. I implemented my logic in the other answer, I might have understood wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ to achive this:

`var commonList = list1.Intersect(list2)`

Comment: Given that the method declaration shown returns a `bool`, I would think that the OP only wants to know whether there is an intersection, not actually get that intersection. the wording of the question itself seems to back that up.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

I am not sure if this is what you wanted, but i will post anyways. This algorithm lets you compare the values from List 1 with the values AHEAD from List 2.

Example: List 1 Index 2 compared from List 2 Index 2 to the last value.

Even if this is not what you needed, i hope it helps someone.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ListCompareItems
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> myList1 = new List<string>{ "123", "234", "345" };
            List<string> myList2 = new List<string> { "987", "123", "345", "112" };
            var comparisonLogic = (from item1 in myList1
                                  where (myList2.GetRange(
                                            myList1.IndexOf(item1),
                                            myList2.Count() - 1 - myList1.IndexOf(item1)).ToList().Contains(item1)
                                  )
                                  select item1).ToList();

            foreach (var output in comparisonLogic)
                Console.WriteLine(output);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

123

345

**Extras**

You can edit this algorithm to return another answers.

If you want to know if there is at least one match, `Count()` the comparisonLogic. If it is greater than 0, there is a match.

You can return the `Count()` itself to know how many times there was a match.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `Intersect...Any`(might be more efficient than [`Any...Contains`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72953325/284240)):

```
bool intersectsWith = list1.Intersect(list2).Any();
```

By default it's using `StringComparison.Ordinal` which is case sensitive. If you want to compare in a case insensitive manner use

```
bool intersectsWith = list1.Intersect(list2, StringConmparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase).Any();
```

Comment: is this case sensitive?

Comment: @toha: Yes, by default it's using `StringComparison.Ordinal` which is case sensitive(like `"String1"=="string1"`). If you want to compare in a case insensitive manner use `list1.Intersect(list2, StringConmparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`. Added to answer

Comment: ok thanks. I will use this sometimes